# Hi, I am Stuck at Java script in Lwc, Can Anyone help me

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, general

I am using hasOwnProperty in Js in Lwc. if there are 10 records and 1 records parentId is empty, remain 9 records are not displaying due to 1 record. how to over come this point. can any one suggest me. how can I make sure if parent is empty, equal to Null. to display all 10 records

js:

```
getoppRecords({objectName: this.selectedObject,account:this.tempAccount,
    fieldName:this.selectedField,
            currentUser:this.currentUser.Id,
            region:this.tempRegion})
                .then((result) =>{
                this.isLoading = false;
                let tempData=result.map(function (item) {
                    return{...item,
                            rowSelect:false,
                            currentRecordLink: item.hasOwnProperty('Id') ? '/' + item.Id : '',
                            RegAccName:(item.hasOwnProperty('Account'))? item.Account.Parent.Name:'',
                            
                    };
                    },this);
this.RealData = tempData;
})
```

HTML :

```
<template>
<th width="175px" rowspan="2"  style="left:50px; z-index:4;  ">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" data-sortdirection={sortDirection} onclick={handleSortData} title="Name">Name</div>
                             
                        </th>
<th width="175px" rowspan="2"  style="left:50px; z-index:4;  ">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" data-sortdirection={sortDirection} onclick={handleSortData} title="Regional Account">Regional Account</div>
                             
                        </th>

<template for:each={objectRecords} for:item="item">
<td class="slds-truncate priceRecordstd">
                                <div class={item.textColor} title={item.Name}>{item.Name}</div>
                            </td>
<td class="slds-truncate priceRecordstd">
                                <div class={item.textColor} title={item.RegAccName}>{item.RegAccName}</div>
                            </td>
 </template>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need hasOwnProperty method you can try below code-

```
 getoppRecords({objectName: this.selectedObject,account:this.tempAccount,
fieldName:this.selectedField,
        currentUser:this.currentUser.Id,
        region:this.tempRegion})
            .then((result) =>{
            this.isLoading = false;
            let tempData=result.map(function (item) {
                return{...item,
                        rowSelect:false,
                        currentRecordLink: item.hasOwnProperty('Id') ? '/' + item.Id : '',
                        RegAccName:item.Account ? (item.Account.Parent ? item.Account.Parent.Name : '') : '',
                        
                };
                },this);
```

Comment: Thank You. It is working.

Comment: Please upvote if it helps.